# Количество элементов в списке

Tags: javascript, dom

Как посчитать количество элементов li в списке? 
У меня такой пример кода, но он неправильный, как его отредактировать?

```js
let li = document.getElementById('ul');
console.log(li.childElementCount);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы спутали getElementById с [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
console.log(li.childElementCount);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы строкой

```
let li = document.getElementById('ul');
```

просите дать Вам элемент страницы с `id='ul'`. Но у Вас на странице нет такого элемента. Измените `<ul>` на `<ul id="ul">` и все будет работать